# if elem is clicked, detect if form elems have changed, if so #anchor

Tags: javascript

- I am trying to check first if my elem '`update`' has been clicked.
- *If* it has, I'd like to run a function that will detect *if* any of my
  '`form`' elements have changed. On *change* function.
- If a form element has *changed*, I'd like to fire my `jumptoUpdate();`
  function, which would scroll the user back down to my '`update`' elem.
- I need this to run continuously, in case the user keeps changing a
  for elem; if so anchor down to '`update`' elem each time.
- But this should only run *AFTER* my '`update`' elem has been clicked
  once.

  ---

**Below is my attempt.**

```
// if user has clicked 'update' then begin check on change
    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

      const goCheckR = document.getElementById('update');
      let el = event.target;
      while(el && el !== goCheckR) el = el.parentElement;
      if(!el) return;

        function jumptoUpdate(){
            var top = document.getElementById("update").offsetTop;
            window.scrollTo(0, top);
        }

        addEventHandler(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                addEventHandler(document.getElementById('mainform'), 'change', 

                function() {
                    setInterval( jumptoUpdate, 500);
                });
             });   

        console.log(event.target);

    }, false);
```

*Vanilla JS (no jQuery or libs)*

Comment: Why do you have `addEventHandler` and are also using `addEventListener`?

Comment: why not simply use Flag? once it clicked put on flag - true and then you will know

Comment: Hmm.. I have not used 'flag'; how so?

Comment: This is unclear: *detect if any of my 'form' elements have changed*: changed since when? Can `update()` change the content of the forms?

Comment: Since the 'update' has been clicked.... There is no 'update();' function.

Comment: @No-Spex use _a_ flag, not the flag . It just means to set a variable to true or false, and then when the expected event occurs to change that variable's value